# how to parse HTML tags to plain text?I want to achive something like facebook or twitter

Tags: php, jquery

For example: I have this string

```
@[1234:peterwateber] <b>hello</b> <div>hi!</div> http://stackoverflow.com
```

I want to convert it into HTML like this:

```
<a href="1234">@peterwateber</a> &lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt; &lt;div&gt;hi!&lt;divb&gt; 
<a href="http://sackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

I'm using QueryPath, and I have this code where you can get the texts from **"@[123:peterwateber]"** to be outputted to "**123** and **peterwateber**" respectively.

```
The code to do that is:
$hidden_input = "@[1234:peterwateber] <b>hello</b> <div>hi!</div> http://stackoverflow.com";
preg_match('#@\[(\w+)\:(\w+)\]#', $hidden_input, $m); //returns 123,peterwateber
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have this kind of output:
 [image: Facebook Style Post or Twitter Style Post]

I'm using Hawkee's plugin for jQuery autocomplete **http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/**

Comment: already answered! answer to this question is found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052101/jquery-javascript-change-text-with-to-link/10052203#comment12862482_10052203

Comment: Does this help? Idk if you saw it because google results change so quickly. :)
http://psoug.org/snippet/Convert-HTML-to-plain-text_36.htm

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirly sure if there is a specific function just for that but what you can do is this:
in example of the link (a href)

```
$raw = "@[1234:peterwateber]"
$thingtoreplace = ("@[");
$firstpass = str_replace($thingtoreplace, "<a href='", $raw);
$raw2 = $firstpass
$thingtoreplace = (":");
$secondpass = str_replace($thingtoreplace, "'>", $raw1);
$raw3 = $second
$thingtoreplace = ("]");
$secondpass = str_replace($thingtoreplace, "'</a>", $raw3);
```

I know it seems tedious but it should do the trick.  If its not helpful then please dont rate me down... I spent time on this

Comment: thanks but I did that... Its been like 3 days finding answer for this one... the part where preg_match('#@\[(\w+)\:(\w+)\]#', $hidden_input, $m);  should do the trick where you can "123 and peterwateber" from "@[123:peterwateber]" the problem would be converting it to an anchor tag and afterwards parsing the whole string like my screenshot above. thanks though this is really hard. I can't figure this out...