# Loading HTML from jQuery Ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a jQuery Ajax POST request to a PHP script that returns an HTML select menu complete with all its options.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "books/editions",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(menu) {
        $('#editions').html(menu);
    }
});
```

Debugging tells me that the PHP script is executed properly and is returning the HTML select menu as expected. However, Firebug is telling me that 'menu' is undefined -- and obviously nothing is loaded into the '#editions' div.

I was expecting 'menu' to contain the HTML string returned from the PHP function, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

--

As requested, the PHP editions() method code:

```
public function editions()
{
    $menu = $this->books_repository->get_editions_menu();
    return $menu;
}
```

Again, debugging at the return point tells me that the method is returning an HTML string that is properly formatted with the correct contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function editions() {
   $menu = $this->books_repository->get_editions_menu();
   //return $menu; when ajax jQuery is used, make sure the output is printed
   echo $menu;
}
```

Comment: in your php part was it $_POST[somename]? the data in ajax: what is dataString?

Comment: Thx for responding. Yes, 'dataString' contains the variables needed by the PHP function to return the HTML string. I know that part is working correctly because the string is returned from PHP as expected.

Comment: is your url:"controller/method"?

Comment: Yes that's correct - the editions() method is returning the HTML string as expected.

Comment: there might be something wrong with your php part the editions method can you post the codes here?

Comment: Please also include the model

Comment: Now I see the problem don't use return. use echo

Comment: Always remember, when outputing from php to ajax, never use return use print, or echo or something...

Comment: @peter - please edit your answer so that the solution can be found in it and future users don't need to read through the comments to find it.  Funny how you sort of did it backwards, putting what amounts to a comment as an answer, then actually answering the question with a comment.

Comment: @gilly3 sorry I was watching over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051232/how-to-parse-html-tags-to-plain-text-i-wanna-achive-something-like-facebook (can't find an answer though can you help me?)