# jquery,javascript change text with @ to link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I have this string

> @[123:peterwateber] **hello!** good day!

I wanna change it to `<a href="123">peterwateber</a> &lt;b&gt;hellow!&lt;/b&gt;! good day!`

what I want to do first, from the given string, get first the @[123:peterwateber] convert it to an anchor tag and the remaining string with htmlspecialchars will be parsed to plain text. How to do this?

I did the first one using php by this code: `preg_match('#@\[(\w+)\:(\w+)\]#', $hidden_input, $m)` but I wanna do it in jquery or javascript this time... any suggestions? I badly need your help guys its been 3 days solving this problem :(

Comment: @nathanjosiah ive been using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Hawkee/vq6MH/1/  My approach is to have something like twitter or facebook where you "@mention" someone. once the message is saved and fetch from the databse, the output would be a link and a parsed plain text of htmlspecialchars and links to someone who is mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex replace in javascript**

```
'@[123:peterwateber] hello! good day!'.replace(
    /@\[(.*):(.*)\](.*)/,
    '<a href="$1">$2</a>$3'
 )
```

Comment: woow thats great mate! I love you mate! finally! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!

one last question, what will be the best way to parse html tags? i mean my approach is like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051232/how-to-parse-html-tags-to-plain-text-i-wanna-achive-something-like-facebook

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
var text = 'And then @[123:peterwateber] said "Hello world!". After that @[123:nathanjosiah] was talking about a jsfiddle';

text = text.replace(/@\[(\d+)\:(\w+)\]/g, '<a href="$1">$2</a>')
// output: And then <a href="123">peterwateber</a> said "Hello world!". After that <a href="123">nathanjosiah</a> was talking about a jsfiddle
```

Comment: what if you add some htmlspecial chars? like these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051232/how-to-parse-html-tags-to-plain-text-i-wanna-achive-something-like-facebook

Comment: If you want to parse the entities to actual html you would use `$('<div/>').html(text).text()`